How to 're-export' @use ... with vars from a SASS partial
I have a situation where I am using @use ... with to load styles from a component library and customise some of the values
e.g.
@use '@material/theme' with (
  $background: #fff,
  $surface: #f0f6ff,
  $on-primary: #fff,
  $on-secondary: #fff,
);

but I then want to use my customised $surface var in other files
So my question is how to have this @use ... with statement in one file "theme.scss" and then @use 'theme.scss' in my other files?
I tried @use 'theme.scss' as *; but I get undefined variable errors when I try to use $surface in the other file.

What worked for me is:
@use '@material/theme' with (
  $background: #fff,
  $surface: #f0f6ff,
  $on-primary: #fff,
  $on-secondary: #fff,
);

@use '@material/typography' with (
  ...
);

@forward '@material/theme' hide core-styles;
@forward '@material/theme' as theme-* show core-styles;
@forward '@material/typography' hide core-styles;
@forward '@material/typography' as typography-* show core-styles;

I was a bit dubious whether forwarding '@material/theme' would expose the customised value or just the original, but it seems to forward the customised value.
And above I work around the fact that theme and typography both export a core-styles value by prefixing just that key from each, while forwarding all the rest without prefix.
